# 'Conditional join' in MySQL - (Different joins under conditions)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

We have two tables:

Product and Store

A store can essentially have many products. We are selecting from the products table, but we are inner joining it to the stores table so that we only select products who come from a store that is currently 'active'.

However, we only want that behavior to occur if it is not the STORE OWNER that is looking at the given product(s).

So, essentially what I want to do, is have a query that we can supply the currently logged in user_id to the query, and do a join against the stores table. If the supplied user_id matches that in the stores table, then it is the store owner - and we should allow them to view the product [this will essentially join with different conditions]. If the user_id is DIFFERENT from that in the stores table, then it is a regular user, and should not be allowed to view the product.

Here are my two queries:

**Store Owner**

```
SELECT products.* from products
INNER JOIN stores
ON stores.id = products.store_id
AND stores.user_id = <supplied userid>
```

**Regular User**

```
SELECT products.* from products
INNER JOIN stores
ON stores.id = products.store_id
AND stores.is_active = 1
```

I basically want to roll these into one query, if at all possible.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the two tables? Using `UNION ALL` (or just `UNION` for distinct records) could make better use of any indexes. You will be using more code, you may get a better query plan.

Comment: To elaborate, in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37233/1) the union query is able to use indexes on `is_active` and `user_id`, the one using OR uses neither of these indexes and just performs a table scan. On a data set the size of this example it is inconsequential, in a much larger data set this could make a significant difference.

Comment: so you want if ID is found to only see his items, or to see his+all other?

Comment: all + others essentially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT products.* from products
INNER JOIN stores
ON stores.id = products.store_id
AND (stores.user_id = <supplied userid> OR stores.is_active = 1)
```

Comment: this returns active stores as well to the suplier

Comment: Glad to help! I just used the logic from your queries. It really was simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Two inner joins should do the trick.

```
SELECT products.* from products
INNER JOIN stores owners_store ON ( owners_store.id = products.store_id AND owners_store.user_id = <supplied userid> )
INNER JOIN stores user_stores ON ( user_stores.id = products.store_id AND user_stores.is_active = 1 )
```